# Can I run cpplint from within code::blocks?

Tags: codeblocks, cpplint

Is it possible to run Google's [cpplint.py](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py) from within Code::Blocks, so I can jump from one error to the next in the source code?

For those unfamiliar with cpplint.py, it's a python script that flags lines that violate the [Google Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html). It outputs error messsages in the same format as gcc's compiler errors, so emacs for example has no trouble the error spew correctly to step from one flagged line to the next.

Comment: It's certainly possible to run the tool, but in order to parse the output and jump from one error to the next, you will need to write a plugin. There is a cppcheck plugin which you can use to start with (it does just that, only with cppcheck, not cpplint -- should be easy enough to modify).

Comment: If the error messages are identical to GCC compiler errors, you might try writing a compiler config script which defines the python exe with the script name as compiler executable. Then you could check your program by changing the build options to use the "cpplint compiler" and "recompile" your program.